# BrowserSync + php server proxy: php requests time out

Tags: php, node.js, browser-sync

I'm trying to proxy a php server to BrowserSync in a Node.js script.
The BS config is just this, and I'm starting a php server with the following:

```
browserSyncConfig = {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
}

php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I'm using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as many suggested (with localhost all resources time out).

All resources load properly except for .php files, they are pending indefinitely. The result is the same with XAMPP, but strangely it works with Mongoose.
What could be the problem with the php -S server?